# Each property name in a type must be unique

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I created one view in my db, ef will alter this error message.
SPL & Segementation are tables, vwSPLGrade is a view.

```
select spl.*,grade.SegmentationDisplay from SPL as spl
left join Segmentation as grade
on UPPER(spl.HCPEID) = UPPER(grade.HCPEID)
where spl.status = 1 and grade.status =1
```

What do I need to do to fix this question?

```
public class SPL : Entity
{
    public SPL() { }

    public string TA { get; set; }
    public string TerritoryCode { get; set; }
    public string YearMonth { get; set; }
    public string HCPEID { get; set; }
    public string HCOVeevaId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FocusDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? SurveyId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsSPL { get; set; }
}

public class Segmentation : Entity
{
    public Segmentation() { }

    public string TA { get; set; }
    public string HCPEID { get; set; }
    public string SegmentationDisplay { get; set; }
    public string SegmentationCalculate { get; set; }
    public string SegmentationMRManual { get; set; }
    public string SegmentationAdminChange { get; set; }
    public Guid? SurveyId { get; set; }
    public string TerritoryCode { get; set; }
    public string YearMonth { get; set; }
}

public class vwSPLGrade : Entity
{
    public vwSPLGrade() { }

    public string TA { get; set; }
    public string TerritoryCode { get; set; }
    public string YearMonth { get; set; }
    public string HCPEID { get; set; }
    public string HCOVeevaId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FocusDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? SurveyId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsSPL { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}

public class SPLMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<SPL>
{
    public SPLMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.ToTable("SPL");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.TA).HasColumnName("TA");
        this.Property(t => t.TerritoryCode).HasColumnName("TerritoryCode");
        this.Property(t => t.YearMonth).HasColumnName("YearMonth");
        this.Property(t => t.HCPEID).HasColumnName("HCPEID");
        this.Property(t => t.HCOVeevaId).HasColumnName("HCOVeevaId");
        this.Property(t => t.FocusDate).HasColumnName("FocusDate");
        this.Property(t => t.SurveyId).HasColumnName("SurveyId");
        this.Property(t => t.IsSPL).HasColumnName("IsSPL");

        this.Property(t => t.Status).HasColumnName("status");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateBy).HasColumnName("create_by");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateDate).HasColumnName("create_date");
        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedBy).HasColumnName("last_modified_by");
        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedDate).HasColumnName("last_modified_date");

    }
}

public class SegmentationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Segmentation>
{
    public SegmentationMap()
    {


        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);


        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.ToTable("Segmentation");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.TA).HasColumnName("TA");
        this.Property(t => t.HCPEID).HasColumnName("HCPEID");
        this.Property(t => t.SegmentationDisplay).HasColumnName("TerritoryCode");
        this.Property(t => t.SegmentationCalculate).HasColumnName("SegmentationCalculate");
        this.Property(t => t.SegmentationMRManual).HasColumnName("SegmentationMRManual");
        this.Property(t => t.SegmentationAdminChange).HasColumnName("SegmentationAdminChange");
        this.Property(t => t.SurveyId).HasColumnName("SurveyId");
        this.Property(t => t.TerritoryCode).HasColumnName("TerritoryCode");
        this.Property(t => t.YearMonth).HasColumnName("YearMonth");

        this.Property(t => t.Status).HasColumnName("status");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateBy).HasColumnName("create_by");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateDate).HasColumnName("create_date");
        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedBy).HasColumnName("last_modified_by");
        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedDate).HasColumnName("last_modified_date");

    }
}

public class vwSPLGradeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<vwSPLGrade>
{
    public vwSPLGradeMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("VW_SPLGrade");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.TA).HasColumnName("TA");
        this.Property(t =>t.TerritoryCode).HasColumnName("TerritoryCode");
        this.Property(t => t.YearMonth).HasColumnName("YearMonth");
        this.Property(t => t.HCPEID).HasColumnName("HCPEID");
        this.Property(t => t.HCOVeevaId).HasColumnName("HCOVeevaId");
        this.Property(t => t.FocusDate).HasColumnName("FocusDate");
        this.Property(t => t.SurveyId).HasColumnName("SurveyId");
        this.Property(t => t.IsSPL).HasColumnName("IsSPL");
        this.Property(t => t.Grade).HasColumnName("Grade");
        this.Property(t => t.Status).HasColumnName("status");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateBy).HasColumnName("create_by");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateDate).HasColumnName("create_date");
     this.Property(t=>t.LastModifiedBy).HasColumnName("last_modified_by");
this.Property(t=>t.LastModifiedDate).HasColumnName("last_modified_date");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this because both `spl` and `grade` in that query have some column names that are the same?  You're selecting `*` from `spl`.

Comment: @BrendanGreen The full script is
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[VW_SPLGrade]
AS
SELECT        spl.Id, spl.TA, spl.TerritoryCode, spl.YearMonth, spl.HCPEID, spl.HCOVeevaId, spl.FocusDate, spl.SurveyId, spl.IsSPL, spl.status, spl.create_by, spl.create_date, spl.last_modified_by, spl.last_modified_date, 
                         grade.SegmentationDisplay AS Grade
FROM            dbo.SPL AS spl LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Segmentation AS grade ON UPPER(spl.HCPEID) = UPPER(grade.HCPEID)
WHERE        (spl.status = 1) AND (grade.status = 1)

Answer (score 0):

The full error message is

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   TerritoryCode: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'TerritoryCode' is already defined.

I make a mistake of mapping `SegmentationDisplay` to column name `TerritoryCode`.

```
public class SegmentationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Segmentation>
{
    public SegmentationMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        this.Property(t => t.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.ToTable("Segmentation");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.TA).HasColumnName("TA");
        this.Property(t => t.HCPEID).HasColumnName("HCPEID");
        //it should be this.Property(t => t.SegmentationDisplay).HasColumnName("SegmentationDisplay"); 
        this.Property(t => t.SegmentationDisplay).HasColumnName("TerritoryCode"); 
        this.Property(t => t.SegmentationCalculate).HasColumnName("SegmentationCalculate");
        this.Property(t => t.SegmentationMRManual).HasColumnName("SegmentationMRManual");
        this.Property(t => t.SegmentationAdminChange).HasColumnName("SegmentationAdminChange");
        this.Property(t => t.SurveyId).HasColumnName("SurveyId");
        this.Property(t => t.TerritoryCode).HasColumnName("TerritoryCode");
        this.Property(t => t.YearMonth).HasColumnName("YearMonth");

        this.Property(t => t.Status).HasColumnName("status");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateBy).HasColumnName("create_by");
        this.Property(t => t.CreateDate).HasColumnName("create_date");
        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedBy).HasColumnName("last_modified_by");
        this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedDate).HasColumnName("last_modified_date");
    }
}
```